# Hibernate afterAfterTransactionCompletion interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, interceptor

Is there a way to listen the event **after**AfterTransactionCompletion (2 time after) ?

I'm working on an app where the user can modify an entity and save it:

```
tx.begin();
entity.name = "Archimede";
em.merge(entity);
tx.commit();
```

I'd like to intercept the commit, and "correct" the entity. Let's say: if name.equal("Archimede") then the interceptor should change the surname = "Pitagorico".

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[]     previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    changedEntities.add(entity); //register all changing entities
}

public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
    for(T entity : changedEntities) {
        if(entity.name.euqual("Archimede")) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            entity.surname = "Pitagorico";
            sendNotificationToUser();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's not allowed to use entityManager or transaction in the interceptor, and this will fail with something like :

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: reuse of Transaction instances not supported
```

The guilty one is here (org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl):

```
@Override
public void commit() throws HibernateException {
    if ( localStatus != LocalStatus.ACTIVE ) {
        throw new TransactionException( "Transaction not successfully started" );
    }

    LOG.debug( "committing" );

    beforeTransactionCommit();

    try {
        doCommit();
        localStatus = LocalStatus.COMMITTED;
        afterTransactionCompletion( Status.STATUS_COMMITTED ); //<-------
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        localStatus = LocalStatus.FAILED_COMMIT;
        afterTransactionCompletion( Status.STATUS_UNKNOWN );
        throw new TransactionException( "commit failed", e );
    }
    finally {
        invalidate(); //<-------
        afterAfterCompletion(); //<-------
    }
}
```

the interceptor is called by **afterTransactionCompletion( Status.STATUS_COMMITTED );**, but this is prior to **invalidate();**, and the transaction is still in a COMMIT state.
Just in the next line it call afterAfterCompletion();, and at this point the transaction should be valid and ready to **.begin()**.

I'd like to have an interceptor method here, so the previous code should not have any problems.

Anyone know a way? Or is my approach wrong? (Any better one?)

Comment: why don'y you use @PrePersist annotation ?

Comment: also in @PrePersist i should not use EntityManager or Transaction, and i'd like to "correct" the entity only if, and when, the transaction actually commit (not if rollback). Moreover the transaction should not depend on the "correction" (if the correction fail just the correction transaction should fail, not the first one). They should be two separated transaction.

Comment: Why do I have a feeling of seeing unsafe code for concurrency ? Having the entity as instance field you are making it bad. What do you think ?

Comment: Why not correct the entity during the onFlushDirty?

Answer (score 1):

I would use some AOP and would play with the @Transactions

ex :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
public MyEntity doSaveService(MyEntity myentity){
  em.merge(myentity); // not required but easier to read
  em.flush(); //not sure if you need it
}
```

Add some AOP on this merge method (with some annotations or XML declaration as you want)

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
protected Object postMergeProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
 MyEntity myEntityBeforeMerge = (MyEntity ) proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];
 MyEntity myEntityAfterMerge = (MyEntity ) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
 myEntityAfterMerge.setWhatever("xxx");
 em.merge();
}
```

XML :

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect ref="">
    <aop:pointcut id="mergePointCut" expression="execution(* x.y.z.EntityService.merge(..))" />
            <aop:around method="postMergeProcess" pointcut-ref="mergePointCut" />
 </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: thank you, this may work. But i don't get the merge method, can't i just bind the advice on the EntityManager#merge() method? I'll must react to tx.commit() but the principle it's the same. I'm using google guice, i hope its AOP will suffice. The only problem i can think right now is for managed entities update, if i dont explicitly call merge(), is there a way to force me to do so?

Comment: Edit : I change the merge method with an explicit name. AOP interception should be done on your service layer or something like that. You could try on the Entity.merge too. I am not sure about the behaviour in this case.

Comment: i've wrapped the EntityManager, so i can intercept persist, merge, remove and trasaction.commit but, i just realized, that intercepting merge and not onFlushDirty i lose currentState,previousState and propertyNames, so now i can't tell which property has changed. (and merge does not even mean the entity has changed at all). Any ideas?

Comment: Well in my example you have a myEntityBeforeMerge and myEntityAfterMerge. So you can retrieve which property has changed. Otherwise I have no idea without a real source code.

Comment: If i get it right, myEntityBeforeMerge is the entity before merge (but with the modifications to be saved) and myEntityAfterMerge is the managed entity, so the content is the same. I'd need the original entity status, before any user modifications (the state on the db).

Comment: I've created another question with an idea how to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574638/jpa-and-aop-callbacks